# Users-Posts-Comments relationship implementation on reliable collections

Tags: list, dictionary, data-structures, azure-service-fabric

Let's imagine I have three classes: `User`,`Post`, `Comment`. Standard actions — user can create posts and write comments to these posts. So we have the situation depicted below: [image]

I need to perform these three queries very quickly:

- Get all comments for a post
- Get all comments for a user
- Get post for a comment

And it looks like it isn't possible even if I will use partitioning. At least not with a single reliable dictionary. Probably I need several dictionaries for different queries. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on the same thing! First of all: My schema is a bit different. I have a user, a topic and a comment. The topic is just a class with a list of comment ids(IEnumerable long), nothing more. The first comment is the post.

Oh, really first of all, little warning: I'm just beginning with Service Fabric, so I might be doing it wrong ;)

The user is not relevant for me. I just store the userid on the comment. When retrieving a list of comments I get the users from the stateful users service. Or I will store the users name in the comment directly, not sure yet.

So that leaves me with topics and comments. First I thought 'lets create a Stateful TopicService and a Stateful CommentService'. But then I realised that for every topic I load I need to call the CommentService for each comment to get the comments.

So I created a TopicService which handles 2 IReliableDictionaries: topics and comments.

Whenever a comment is posted I use the TopicId as the partitionkey and in that partition the comment is stored. So NOT using the commentid !! This way all the comments for a specific topic are in the same partition.

When loading a topic with all the comments I use the TopicId as the partitionkey again, get the topic from the reliabledictionary for the topics and loop the list of comment ids in the reliabledictionary for the comments. Not sure if it helps, but my GetComments looks like this:

```
        var topics = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<long, TopicModel>>("topics");
        var comments = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<long, CommentModel>>("comments");

        List<CommentModel> result = new List<CommentModel>();

        using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            ConditionalValue<TopicModel> topic = await topics.TryGetValueAsync(tx, topicid);

            if(topic.HasValue)
            {
                foreach(long commentid in topic.Value.CommentsInternal)
                {
                    ConditionalValue<CommentModel> comment = await comments.TryGetValueAsync(tx, commentid);

                    if (comment.HasValue)
                        result.Add(comment.Value);
                }
            }

            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }

        return result;
```

I'm not done yet, the method some more work.

Perhaps this helps you :)

edit: ow, there is a disadvantage! When you want to load a single comment by its id, you need to provide the topicid. So my CommentModel class has a CommentId and a TopicId property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about partitioning, but it seemed to me a little bit “complicated”, and I continued searching for a simplier solution.
How you will get all comments for a particular user?
Why do you call `CommitAsync` as there no changes to reliable collections?
Are you storing comments in a list inside a reliable dictionary? If so, it is not thread-safe and should be avoided.

Comment: Partitioning is not that difficult. Its all about grouping data on a node. Service Fabric does the most work for that. It also depends on how many comments will be. If its in the thousands, dont bother partitioning. If its in the hunderd thousands... partition! All the comments for a particular user could be done with Azure Search or keeping a seperate index. I commit as a habbit. I have a transaction, so I end it with a commit. Comments in a list yes, I use an Actor (with None persistence) to edit the data. Actors are behaving single threaded. Write=Actor, Read=Stateful Service.

Comment: So, one actor per topic to store comments or it is stored in service and you only editing data, calling service's methods from an actor? How many user can simultaneously add/remove new comments to topics?

Comment: The Actor is only used for write actions. Read actions go directly to the Stateful Service. The Actor has no state, so the persistence state is set to None(the attribute above the Actor class). The Topic only holds an array of comment ID's, so its very light. It takes about 9ms to add a comment to a topic. Thats 111 comments per second(!). If thats not enough, you could skip the Actor and create a stateful service with a queue which adds the comment id's to the topic. This might add a small  delay when its really busy(hunderds of comments per sec), but will be almost instant on quite hours.

Comment: Why you decided to write through actors and read through service?

Comment: Because the Actor is single threaded, so only 1 write action at the time. But I'm thinking about changing it to a queue mechanism. Also: I'm just beginning with Service Fabric, so I'm learning as I'm going ;) Just sharing my experiences so far!